# Overlay 2 pdf files into one

Tags: pdf

I have two separate pdf files, each 50 pages. I want to overlay one file on top of the other one, with the output being a single pdf document of 50 pages, with the content of the two pdfs overlayed page-wise.

I don't want the same page of document 2 as the background of document 1, but each page should merge. i.e page one of pdf 1 merge with page one of pdf 2, page two of pdf 1 merge with page two of pdf 2, etc.

I have found some expensive software that will do it, but I only have this one thing to do. Is there any freeware out there that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already nicely answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501723/overlay-one-pdf-or-ps-file-on-top-of-another):

> You can do this with pdf files using the command line tool [pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/)
>   using the `stamp` or `background` option.
>
> ```
> $ pdftk file1.pdf background file2.pdf output combinedfile.pdf
> ```
>
> This will only work with a one-page background file.  If you have
>   multiple pages, you can use the
>   [`multibackground`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-multibackground)
>   command instead.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be done using MANY cross platform command line products such as

- [pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/) now fairly old (2.02 - July 24, 2013) as mentioned by farosch
- [cpdf](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) a much more powerful and up to date command line toolkit

but **both of the above are not free for commercial users**
 
 
 
the **free open source for commercial users** (subject to license) include

- [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) a powerhouse of abilities many way beyond pdftk   (Apache License Version 2.0)
- [pdfcpu](http://pdfcpu.io/core/stamp) very good toolkit including a multi-stamp similar to pdftk  (Apache License Version 2.0)