# How to overlay two pdfs page-by-page in Arch? (without pdftk)

Tags: pdf, arch-linux

Recently, I sent a draft of a paper to my professor, who edited the document red pen style, handwritten on his tablet with a stylus, and emailed me back his commentary. This wouldn't be a problem, except that, for some reason, the pdf he sent me contained **only** his commentary-- without the original document that was written over.

How would one go about overlaying this commentary with the original file, so that I can read it?

This question already has (I think) an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1171969/overlay-2-pdfs-file-into-one) using pdftk; however, I am using an arch machine with a fairly minimal setup, so I am wondering if there is a different solution with less dependencies.

Comment: The simplest solution is to email your professor back the incomplete document he sent you and ask him to send you the marked up and complete document.

Comment: @music2myear I did! But that was just what inspired the question. I'm still interested in knowing how to do it for future reference. I can think of many other scenarios in which this could be useful.