# Can a scan be combined with a text PDF to make a searchable PDF without OCR?

Tags: pdf, scanning

I have some legal documents in PDF form that need my signature on some pages. I would like to store these, including my scanned signature, online. I plan to use tools to concatenate the pages that don't require my signature with those that do. Is there a way to make all of the pages searchable *without OCR*, given that I have the original PDF, which is searchable.

This is similar to the question [How to make a searchable PDF document from a scan AND a source Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/405696/how-to-make-a-searchable-pdf-document-from-a-scan-and-a-source-word-document), posted in 2012, which never got an answer that did not involve OCR.

Comment: I welcome suggestions or edits to come up with a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to **insert** an image into an existing PDF using online tools or an application, e.g., [online PDF editor, Adobe Acrobat, or Preview for macOS](https://www.wikihow.com/Insert-an-Image-Into-PDF). [Nitro PDF](https://www.gonitro.com/user-guide/pro/article/insert-add-image-to-a-pdf) and [PhantomPDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/blog/basic-pdf-editing-skills-how-to-edit-pdf-images-using-foxit-phantompdf/) are other commercial applications to edit a PDF file.

Some *caveats*, though:

- If this is a legal document with personal information or with restricted availability, you might want to avoid online services.
- Make a copy of the document, with a different filename from the original, add the image, and test that it is still searchable with the image.
- Keep the original PDF and image files. Zipped together, they should take up no more room then the PDF with image inline.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there would be a way for that.

Also it'd be risky as without an OCR there is no way to make sure text and scan is actually the same.